# resolution problem in 12.04 i am using i3

Tags: resolution

Hello I am using i3processor3.2 speed and asus p8 H61-M LX3 R2.0 mother board, I am getting low resolution can any one please say how i can clear that problem

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide more hardware information. Include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(vga|graphics)"` in your question (edit it). Also include if you have installed any drivers currently for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the graphic card driver.

Open *Ubuntu Software Center* -> *Software packages* -> *Extra drivers* (I think)